# Sort distributed couples from two lists

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Having two lists, I want to get all the possible couples. (a couple can be only one element from list 1 and another from list 2)

If I do a double "foreach" statement, I get it immediately (I am using python):

```
couples = []
for e1 in list_1:
    for e2 in list_2:
        couples.append([l1, l2])
```

How can I sort couples list in a way that elements be placed in a more distributed way?
for example:

```
list_1 = [a,b,c]
list_2 = [1,2]
```

I will get:

```
[a, 1]
[a, 2]
[b, 1]
[b, 2]
[c, 1]
[c, 2]
```

And expect to be sorted to something like this:

```
[a, 1]
[b, 2]
[c, 1]
[a, 2]
[b, 1]
[c, 2]
```

What algorithm should I use to get this results?

Comment: Why does [b,2] come before [b,1] ?

Comment: How important is the order? (eg: would *not* having an order be acceptable)?

Comment: Do you want them to be in a randomized order?

Comment: I think what the OP wants is this: If you see the output as a table (the first column having a/b/c, the second having 1/2), he wants an order that still is as sorted as possible for each column, but also each column should avoid runs (like in the first example: a, a, a, b, b, b ...)

Comment: I think what you refer to as "couples" is more commonly known as "pair".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from itertools import islice, izip, cycle

list_1 = ['a','b','c']
list_2 = [1,2]

list(islice(izip(cycle(list_1), cycle(list_2)), len(list_1)*len(list_2)))
```

Returns `[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('c', 2)]`

Comment: This gives different pairs only if `bool(len(list_1) % len(list_2)) & bool(len(list_2) % len(list_1)) == True` ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You should check out [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from the stdlib.

Edit: I meant `product()`, not `permutations()`.

```
import itertools

list_1 = ['a','b','c']
list_2 = [1,2]

# To pair list_1 with list_2 
paired = list(itertools.product(list_1, list_2))
# => [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 1), ('c', 2)]

# To get the sorting you desired:
wanted = sorted(paired, key=lambda x: x[1])
# [('a', 1), ('b', 1), ('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 2), ('c', 2)]
```

Since `product()` returns an iterator, you don't need to cast it to a `list()` (and with large lists you probably shouldn't.) I just added that for illustration in this example should decide to test it yourself and want to print the values.

Comment: +1 for suggesting using the standard libraries and linking to docs

Comment: Close, but the function the OP wrote is itertools.product

Comment: thanks, for the response, but I actually mean to "unsort" eumiro solutions is what needed.

Answer (score 0):

To do the the way you want and you could flip the values:

```
>>> z = [[k, l] for l in x for k in y]
>>> z
[[1, 'a'], [2, 'a'], [3, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'b'], [1, 'c'], [2, 'c'], [3, 'c']]
>>> z.sort()
>>> z
[[1, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [1, 'c'], [2, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [2, 'c'], [3, 'a'], [3, 'b'], [3, 'c']]
>>> T = [[x[1], x[0]] for x in z]
>>> T
[['a', 1], ['b', 1], ['c', 1], ['a', 2], ['b', 2], ['c', 2], ['a', 3], ['b', 3], ['c', 3]]
```

Comment: I didn't downvoted this. Probably I was not very specific but @eumiro solution is what I was looking for. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In pseudo code (not pretty sure about python's syntax) :

given list_1 of size n, and list_2 of size m:

```
couples = []
for i=0 to n-1
   for j=0 to m-1
      couples.append( [ list_1[i], list_2[ (i+j) % m] ] )
```